# how to improve this method using polymorphism+overloading so as to reduce IS (type check)?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overloading

For example

```
BaseClass MyBase()
{
    public int Add(BaseClass next)
    {
        if (this is InheritedA && next is InheritedA)
            return 1;
        else if (this is InheritedA && next is InheritedB)
            return 2;
        else if (this is InheritedB && next is InheritedA)
            return 3;
        else if (this is InheritedB && next is InheritedB)
            return 4;      
     }
}
```

where `InheritedA`, and `InheritedB` are its inherited classes. In fact, there are more Inherited classes, and the `Add` returns different results based on the order and types of its operand.

I am thinking of rewriting it using Polymorphism and overloading, however, it becomes rather complicated, I have to introduce an helper method to resolve the type of either end.

e.g.

```
InheritedA myA()
{
    public override int Add(BaseClass next)
    {
        return next.AddTo(this);
    }
}
```

Now I have to put `AddTo` into `BaseClass`, and override it in inherited class as well.

```
InheritedA myA()
{
    public override int AddTo(InheritedA next) { return 1; }
    public override int AddTo(InheritedB next) { return 3; }
}

BaseClass myBase()
{
    public abstract int Add(BaseClass next);
    public abstract int AddTo(InheritedA next);
    public abstract int AddTo(InheritedB next);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: What happens once there is an InheritedC class? IE does A + C = A + B?

Comment: Are there only two values for each operand (lval & rval)?

Comment: @CAbbott I can modify my class to obey this restriction, so yes only two values

Comment: @Sign that depends, but in general A+C != A+B  By the way, Add is an operator which I should name as "Marry" or "Cat" just to distinguish with addition in common sense

Comment: could you give some 'context' to this? i.e. I'm guessing you're trying to simplify the 'real life' scenario, but it makes all the difference 'how' you're 'calling' the Add, what operators are doing, the big picture, do you have a hierarchy - and 'is it always about comparing types' - e.g. what do you do with 'Add' with the result afterwards, do you combine even more of those - ...

Comment: difficult to understand the question.

Answer (score 9):

The pattern you are implementing is called *double virtual dispatch*.

A *single virtual dispatch* chooses which method to call on the basis of the *run-time type* of the receiver and the *compile time type* of the arguments. This is a traditional virtual dispatch:

```
abstract class Animal {}
class Tiger : Animal {}
class Giraffe : Animal {} 
class B
{
    public virtual void M(Tiger x) {}
    public virtual void M(Animal x) {}
}
class D : B
{
    public override void M(Tiger x) {}
    public override void M(Animal x) {}
}
...
B b = whatever;
Animal a = new Tiger();
b.M(a);
```

Which method is called? `B.M(Tiger)` and `D.M(Tiger)` are not chosen; we reject them based on the *compile time* type of the argument, which is Animal. But we choose whether to call `B.M(Animal)` or `D.M(Animal)` at runtime based on whether `whatever` is `new B()` or `new D()`.

*Double virtual* dispatch chooses which method to call based on the runtime types of *two things*. If C# supported double virtual dispatch, which it does not, then the runtime dispatch would go to `B.M(Tiger)` or `D.M(Tiger)` even though the compile-time type of the argument is *Animal*.

C# 4 does however support *dynamic* dispatch. If you say

```
dynamic b = whatever;
dynamic a = new Tiger();
b.M(a);
```

Then the analysis of M will be done *entirely at runtime* using the runtime types of `b` and `a`. This is significantly slower, but it does work.

Alternatively, if you want to do *double virtual dispatch* and get as much analysis done at compile time as possible then the standard way to do that is to implement the *Visitor Pattern*, which you can look up on the internet easily.

Comment: Really good to know all this.  You said "run-time type of the receiver and the compile time type of the arguments".. but why do you say the runtime type of "a" is not Animal and instead is Tiger ?  I know i can typecast a to Tiger for sure but the type of "a" before typecasting is still Animal. no ?

Comment: @dnkulkarni, the runtime type of something is the actual type at runtime. And the actual type here is `Tiger`, because that's what's actually stored in `a` (or rather, a reference to `Tiger` is).

Comment: @dnkulkarni: The type of *the variable* is Animal. That's the "compile time type" of the expression. The "runtime type" of the expression is the type of the thing that is actually stored in the variable.

Comment: @EricLippert Perhaps this is too much nitpicking, but for a reference type, wouldn't it be better to say "the runtime type is the type of the thing that is actually referred to by the variable"?

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested in the comments, if you are able to assign a constant value to each derived, then you can build a much cleaner implementation than I'm describing here by just having a virtual property named `Value` or similar that is used to for the addition.

Assuming that isn't an option, you may wish to consider pre-computing the results at the base class level to describe the values that you're assigning for each combination.  This can break down and become error prone and tedious as the set of classes grows, so I would suggest only considering this if you expect a very small set to maintain.

In my rudimentary example, I used a dictionary to hold the set and hard-coded the combinations.  From your comment, it appears that none of the basic rules of arithmetic apply, so I've left them out as constraints here.  If the result value has no actual meaning and you're just incrementing it, you could consider building the result set using reflection to pull the derived classes and considering each combination.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  private static readonly Dictionary<int, int> addResults = new Dictionary<int, int>();

  static BaseClass()
  {
    addResults.Add(CreateKey(typeof(ChildA), typeof(ChildA)), 1);
    addResults.Add(CreateKey(typeof(ChildA), typeof(ChildB)), 2);
    addResults.Add(CreateKey(typeof(ChildB), typeof(ChildA)), 3);
    addResults.Add(CreateKey(typeof(ChildB), typeof(ChildB)), 4);
  }

  public static int CreateKey(Type a, Type b)
  {
    return (String.Concat(a.Name, b.Name).GetHashCode());
  }

  public int Add(BaseClass next)
  {
    var result = default(int);

    if (!addResults.TryGetValue(CreateKey(this.GetType(), next.GetType()), out result))
    {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Unknown operand combination");
    }

    return result;
  }
}

public class ChildA : BaseClass {}
public class ChildB : BaseClass {}
```

Comment: i am afraid it would be slower than my version 1?

Comment: It's always tough to speculate on performance, but I would expect the performance to be comparable over a representative data set.  The pre-computed implementation requires a bit more overhead to construct the computed set.  Each call to "Add" would need to allocate memory to do the concatenation and hash value computation, once per call.  The initial implementation is doing the equivalent to GetType for each branch of the conditional by using the "is" operator in the clause.  Unless you are in a real-time system, I don't think performance is a meaningful criterion between the two.