# is there any way to simplify this double conditional clauses structure?

Tags: c#

for example

```
if (x=="A)
    switch (y)
    {
    case "1": Do1();break;
    case "2": Do2();break;
    case "3": Do3();break;
    }
else if (x=="B")
    switch (y)
    {
    case "1": Do4();break;
    case "2": Do5();break;
    case "3": Do6();break;
    }
else
    switch (y)
    {
    case "1": Do7();break;
    case "2": Do8();break;
    case "3": Do9();break;
    }
```

I wish I could do the following, however it has many redundant checks.

```
    if (x=="A" && y=="1")
        Do1();
    else if (x=="A" && y=="2")
        Do2();
    else if (x=="A" && y=="3")
        Do3();
    else if (x=="B" && y=="1")
        Do4();
    else if (x=="B" && y=="2")
        Do5();
    else if (x=="B" && y=="3")
        Do6();
    else if (x=="C" && y=="1")
        Do7();
    else if (x=="C" && y=="2")
        Do8();
    else if (x=="C" && y=="3")
        Do9();
```

Comment: 2 words: Decision tree. You can probably use a dictionary of dictionaries mapped to delegates.

Comment: Another option is to concatenate X and Y into a single string. Might be easier to read as a single level switch.

Comment: Are you finding yourself doing a lot of these checks throughout your code?  If so, this might be a good time to introduce OOP into your project.

Comment: Could "1", "2", "3" be passed as parameters to the target methods e.g. DoA(1), DoA(2), DoA(3)?

Comment: @Tung I tried before, ended up with mess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty/9894768#9894768

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion to introduce OOPS is really great, please do not ignore that comment. For time being you can write your code like this.

```
var combinedText = x+y;
    switch(combinedText)
    {
        case "A1": Do1(); break;
        case "A2": Do2(); break;
        case "A3": Do3(); break;
        case "B1": Do4(); break;
        case "B2": Do5(); break;
        case "B3": Do6(); break;
        case "C1": Do7(); break;
        case "C2": Do8(); break;
        case "C3": Do9(); break;
    }
```

Comment: i tried OOP before, but it didn't work out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty/9894768#9894768

Comment: I saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty/9894768#9894768. You need to give some thought process before you really want to apply OOAD in your project. I can not comment much at this point since I am not fully aware of the code and project. Just discuss the problem within the team, I am very sure there must be a way out.

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, Action> d = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
    {
        {"A1", Do1},
        {"A2", Do2},
        {"A3", Do3},
        {"B1", Do4},
        {"B2", Do5},
        {"B3", Do6},
        {"1", Do7},
        {"2", Do8},
        {"3", Do9}
    };
    var x = "A";
    var y = "1";
    var action = x == "A" || x == "B" ? x + y : y;
    if (d.ContainsKey(action))
        d[action]();
}

public void Do1() {}
public void Do2() {}
public void Do3() {}
public void Do4() {}
public void Do5() {}
public void Do6() {}
public void Do7() {}
public void Do8() {}
public void Do9() {}
```

**EDIT**

I remembered about this [fluent functional switch:](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/03/30/a-functional-c-type-switch.aspx)

```
var sw = new Switch<string>(action)
                    .Case("A1", s => Do1())
                    .Case("A2", s => Do2());
```

Comment: @Lloyd, no reason.. LINQfy it :P. Downvoter, happy to improve the answer, can you explain in which direction?

Comment: I just asked about Linq as it is somewhat cleaner, no downvote on your answer.

Comment: @Lloyd, I know. I simply didn't think at adding LINQ so I had no strong reason for not adding it..

Answer (score 1):

Your code currently has two responsibilities - deciding what set of methods to execute (varible x) and deciding which exact method to execute (varible y). Simplest option to make code much more clear - split this responsibilities and extract methods, that will decide which method from set of methods to call

```
switch (x)
{
    case "A": DoA(y); break;
    case "B": DoB(y); break;
    default:
        DoDefault(y); break;
}
```

Now your caller code is simple. And here is one of DoX methods:

```
private void DoA(string y)
{
    switch (y)
    {
        case "1": Do1(); break;
        case "2": Do2(); break;
        case "3": Do3(); break;
    }
}
```

Other option is to make .net to decide which set of methods to call, by using polymorphism. But in your simple case with only one switch(x) block, I will not recommend to do that. If your real code is more complex, then consider to extract classes which will hold set of functionality (Do1, Do2, Do3) and will decide upon that functionality execution. E.g. calling code:

```
IDo ido = CreateIDo(x);
ido.Do(y);
```

Yes, that's all. Extremely clean. Here is IDo interface creation code:

```
public static IDo CreateIDo(string x)
{
    switch (x)
    {
        case "A": return new A();
        case "B": return new B();
        default:
            return new C();
    }
}
```

And here is class A, that encapsulates first set of methods and decisions upon executing them:

```
public interface IDo
{
    void Do(string y);
}

public class A : IDo
{
    public void Do(string y)
    {
        switch (y)
        {
            case "1": Do1(); break;
            case "2": Do2(); break;
            case "3": Do3(); break;
        }
    }

    private void Do1() { }
    private void Do2() { }
    private void Do3() { }
}
```

Again, use this in case your real code is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an IEnumerable collection of Tuples and an [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) to define your list of methods to be called, create the list as a private field or in the class initialiser, or to be flexible you can add Tuples to a public property as needed. If you need to pass in parameters use one of the overloaded versions of the Action delegate ie: Action(t1, t2) etc.

If you need a return value use the [Func delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) as per the other answer.

```
        IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, Action>> actions = new List<Tuple<string, string, Action>>() { 
        Tuple.Create<string, string, Action>("A", "1", SomeMethod1), 
        Tuple.Create<string, string, Action>("A", "2", SomeMethod2) 
        };

        string x = "A";
        string y = "2";

        var action = actions.FirstOrDefault(t => ((t.Item1 == x) && (t.Item2 == y)));

        if (action != null)
            action.Item3();
        else
            DoSomeDefaultMethod();


        public void SomeMethod1() { // Whatever you want to do  }
        public void SomeMethod2() { // Whatever you want to do  }

        public void DoSomeDefaultMethod() { // Default Method  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this if you don't want to change much of your current structure,(and don't want to create new types etc.)

Add them to tuples like below

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<string,string,Func<>>()>(); // Func should be of your Do() type
```

Add your conditional data with the related funcs to the list

```
tuples.Add(new Tuple<string,string,Func<>>("A","1", Do1()));
...
```

Just call it when required using your conditionals directly

```
var function = tuples.Where(x => x.item1 == "A" && x.item2 == "1").Select(x => x.item3);
function.Invoke(); // to call it.
```

Now if you got more conditionals in future, you can just add them to the list without changing any code.

Answer (score 0):

Use some thing like this . only three if would do.

```
if (x == "A")
{
 int a = (y == "1") ? do1() : ((y == "2") ? do2() : do3());
}
}
    int do1() { return 10; }
    int do2() { return 10; }
    int do3() { return 10; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess the same kind of switch on X is performed in more than one place in your code, if so kindly refactor it and use [polymorphism instead](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

If X is string first [replace the typecode with class](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithClass.html) and use polymorphism.

Comment: How would fix this? Creating 9 + 1 types?

Comment: It is not 9 + 1 it is actually 3 + 3 type

Comment: So if it is 3 + 3 is it better?

Comment: of course you need to create it if the same kind of switch is used in too many places. otherwise how would we maintain it?

Comment: i tried polymorphism before, but it didn't work out gracefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty/9894768#9894768

Comment: Hard to see how using polymorphism would be of any benefit