# Double Dispatch

Tags: c#, design-patterns, double-dispatch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double dispatch in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c)

Can somebody explain what is the *Double Dispatch pattern* in detail with a simple example in *C#*?

I know there are already some questions about this topic on SO, but I dont understand the sense of the [reflection example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587/double-dispatch-in-c). I am sure there are other scenarios where double dispatch can more easily explained.

Comment: @Rookian - That's an automatic comment, added when someone votes to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Oded - Actually, he referenced that question in his, as he apparently didn't understand the examples there.  Had I noticed that it was the very same question he cited I might have chosen a different potential duplicate or not voted to close at all.

Comment: @Rookian - Look for examples of implementing the Visitor Pattern in C#.  This is a principal usage of double dispatch emulation in languages like C# and Java without true multiple dispatch.

Comment: @Rookian maybe you'd want to elaborate, add a specific problem you want solved and then to explain on that very case, might help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892660/how-to-improve-this-method-using-polymorphismoverloading-so-as-to-reduce-is-ty/9894768#9894768